# Trouble embedding Java applet into an html page

Tags: java, html, applet

I currently have a relatively simple Java applet which I am trying to embed into an html page. I've looked around, and haven't found a suitable answer. Many answers refer to using the deprecated `<applet>` tag, and the rest do not seem to work for me.

This is the body of my page. I initially tried using the `<applet>` tag and it worked, however I was unable to get it to use the full height of the page, and then I found it is deprecated anyways.

I've tried this on Firefox, Chrome, and IE, and it won't work on any of them. It only shows the alternative text.

I did read that the `<object>` tag only works for IE, but even so it isn't working for me. Likewise, most of the information I found is outdated.

```
<body>
  <object width="500" height="500" data="project">Your browser does not support the <code>object</code> tag.
  </object>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive had no problems using the applet tag to get applets to display to a desired width and height. All the Java resources point to using the same tags. I'm no html guru though, so I'm not sure if there's another solution.

```
    <applet code= "myJavaApplet.class" width="600" height="700">textgoeshere</applet>
```